# Dynamically object's creation on NSWindow

Tags: objective-c

i did created "UI" objects on ipad

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,60,30)];
[someViewController.someView addSubview:btn];
[btn release];
```

How do i like that, but with NSWindow?

I'm from Russia. Sorry for my bad english:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a desktop app for OSX, the equivalent code would be:

```
NSButton *btn = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(20,20,60,30)];
[someViewController.someView addSubview:btn];
[btn release];
```

Comment: Thanks. But... I have no view, there is only a window. Need to do without the IBOutlet, so I want to port their applications to Linux and Windows. Linux does not support IBOutlet

Comment: Ah, then you can use [[window contentView] addSubview:btn];

Comment: As the answer seems to have been of use to you, you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark so that it turns green.

Comment: Or at least give me an upvote `:)`. I don't really need another ten points, but the success of site is a direct result of the fancy upvote/downvote reputation system.